# Can't obtain the total_loss computed by Keras (empty tensor)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Edit:** Also would help to know, is it possible to get the keras losses of regression and classification separately? I can only obtain a aggregation of the two.

I want to obtain the total loss computed by Keras after model.fit() (see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1653) for more information).

I have created a custom callback which replaces keras validation. So I am using my own session there to have full control over it. I have overrided on_epoch_end loop and I am trying to get total_loss value there.

The code would be something like:

```
# self.model is a tf.keras.models.Model
def on_epoch_end():
    [...]
    total_loss = sess.run([self.model.total_loss]) # error here
    [...]
```

The error that I get is this one:

```
  File "/home/.../callbacks/evaluations/evaluation.py", line 63, in on_epoch_end
    [..., self.model.total_loss]
            │    │     └ <tf.Tensor 'loss/add_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
            │    └ <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f11a25394e0>
            └ <factory.callbacks.evaluations.evaluation.BaseEvaluationCallback object at 0x7f11a1ea2400>

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'classification_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
         [[node classification_target (defined at home/.../trainer.py:91) ]]
         [[loss/add_1/_945]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'classification_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
         [[node classification_target (defined at home/.../trainer.py:91) ]]
```

If anyone has an idea about how could I solve this problem I would be glad to hear it.